# use of class methods in python

Tags: python, oop, class-method

I have a method that works fine but I want it to be a class method, but when I use the @classmethod decorator I get an error indicating that I am missing a parameter that is there (at least as I understand it)

This is the working code and its result:

```
company=Company()
company_collection=company.get_collection('')
for scompany in company_collection:
    print(scompany.get_attrs())

class Entity(Persistent):

    def get_collection(self, conditional_str):
        subset=[]
        collection=[]
        subset=self.get_subset_from_persistant(self.__class__.__name__, conditional_str)
        for entity in subset:
            collection.append(self.get_new_entity(entity))

        return(collection)

class Company(Entity):
    pass

MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:Attractora hvillalobos$ virtual/bin/python3 control.py
{'id': '1', 'razon_social': 'Attractora S.A. de C.V.', 'rfc': ' xxxxxxxx'}
{'id': '2', 'razon_social': 'Otra empresa sa de cv', 'rfc': ' yyyyyyyy'}
{'id': '3', 'razon_social': 'Una mas sa de vc', 'rfc': ' zzzzz'}
```

This the failed one with its result:

```
company_collection=Company.get_collection('')
for scompany in company_collection:
    print(scompany.get_attrs())

class Entity(Persistent):

    @classmethod
    def get_collection(self, conditional_str):
        subset=[]
        collection=[]
        subset=self.get_subset_from_persistant(self.__class__.__name__, conditional_str)
        for entity in subset:
            collection.append(self.get_new_entity(entity))

        return(collection)

class Company(Entity):
    pass

MacBook-Pro-de-Hugo:Attractora hvillalobos$ virtual/bin/python3 control.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "control.py", line 14, in <module>
    company_collection=Company().get_collection('')
  File "/Users/hvillalobos/Dropbox/Code/Attractora/model.py", line 31, in get_collection
     subset=self.get_subset_from_persistant(self.__class__.__name__, conditional_str)
TypeError: get_subset_from_persistant() missing 1 required positional argument: 'conditional_str'
```

I can't find the reason of the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a class method, the first argument should be `cls`, not `self`.  Then, when you call it from the same class, you just do `self. get_subset_from_persistant(conditional_str)`.

You never have to provide the `cls` or `self` parameter when calling a method on a class.

Try this:

```
class Entity(Persistent):

    @classmethod
    def get_collection(cls, conditional_str):
        subset=[]
        collection=[]
        subset=self.get_subset_from_persistant(conditional_str)
        for entity in subset:
            collection.append(self.get_new_entity(entity))

        return(collection)

class Company(Entity):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class method should have this type of signature.

```
@classmethod
def get_collection(cls, conditional_str):
```

`cls` is different from `self` because it refers to the class, i.e. `Entity`

Therfore, you would **NOT** call

```
self.get_subset_from_persistant(self.__class__.__name__, conditional_str)
```

**instead**, you would call

```
cls.get_subset_from_persistant(cls.__name__, conditional_str)
```

Comment: What are the errors? And why do you want to make it a class method?

Comment: I get exactly the same error I was getting before the changes: "get_subset_from_persistant() missing 1 required positional argument: 'conditional_str'". I want it that way because I am learning to use class methods in Python